# cant trigger anchor hover on img mouseenter

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg"></a>
    <div>
        <h4><a href="#">my h4 link</a></h4>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to trigger hover over the `<a>` inside the `<h4>` when the mouse is over the image.

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
$('li img').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('h4 a').trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

That does not work, but if I for example assign it a color via the `css` method it works, for example:

```
$('li img').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('h4 a').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Why isn't the hover working and how do I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `trigger("mouseover");`?

Comment: Seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/T9tE3/  But unless you have code listening for the event, nothing will happen by default.

Comment: Are you wanting the effect that follows the `hover` event in JavaScript or the `:hover` pseudo class specified by CSS (such as a link color change or underline when the mouse hovers over a link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering events via javascript will run the associated javascript event, not the default behavior! So, unless you have a `mouseenter` event defined for that element, nothing will happen.